# how to replace all numbers from a string using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm trying to return a column with every instance of a number replaced by '!'.

the following code only replaces the first instance from each row:

```
select project, commits, contributors, regexp_replace(address, '[0-9]', '!') as address
from repositories
```

`1BcJBCAYqW9` should return as so `!BcJBCAYqW!`
but the output I get is `!BcJBCAYqW9`,
where the second digit does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works as expected in MySQL and Oracle.  So, I am going to guess you are using Postgres or a Postgres-derived database.

Postgres requires an additional argument to specify that all occurrences should be replaced:

```
select regexp_replace(address, '[0-9]', '!', 'g') as address
from (select '1BcJBCAYqW9' as address ) x
```